# How to automatically add layout elements with c#?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I want to add elements into my layout automatically, how do I do that? For example a textview appears when a user clicks a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a `TextView` or any other view in Android you must add the view you want to a view that support addition, one example is the `LinearLayout`.

If you have this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lnrRootView"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And then in you `Activity` add a `TextView` programaticlly to your `LinearLayout`.

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            var linearLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.lnrRootView);

            var textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.Text = "Added programaticlly";
            linearLayout.AddView(textView);
        }
    }
```

You will get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Awesome exactly what I been looking for

Comment: Thank you, you can play with linearlayout orientatioin, and other atributes if you need.

Comment: Do you know how to set the layout_weight of an EditText view programmatically?

Comment: You could do this:
`var tv = new EditText(this);
 var p = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, 1f);
 tv.LayoutParameters = p;
`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Xamarin.Android very well but I think the right way is to add controls to layout with "IsVisible = false", then set IsVisible = true.

Otherwise you can take a look to

```
LinearLayout principalview = FindViewById(Resource.Id.mainlayout);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams parametros = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
    var valueB = new Button(this);
    valueB.Text = "Teste";
    valueB.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Aqua);
    principalview.AddView(valueB, parametros);
```

OR

```
var layout = new LinearLayout (this);
layout.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;

var aLabel = new TextView (this);
aLabel.Text = "Hello, World!!!";

var aButton = new Button (this);
aButton.Text = "Say Hello!";

aButton.Click +=(sender, e) => 
{aLabel.Text="Hello Android!";};

layout.AddView (aLabel);
layout.AddView (aButton);
SetContentView (layout);
```

Comment: I can't do it this way because it would mean that there is a static number of elements, but I don't know how many items a user adds

Comment: @miko If you have a dynamic number of elements, you can use something based on a list.

Answer (score 0):

Much depends on what you're trying to accomplish. You could simulate adding to layout by turning visibility of elements after certain event, eg. button click.

If you want to add elements dynamically during runtime, consider using
`ObservableCollection<T>`

Link: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection%601/